# Could anyone help me with the data processing with R? [Picture Updated]

Tags: r, loops, data-processing

Good morning everyone! I am a newbie of R programming. Recently, I faced some problem.. I would like to process data such as the picture attached. There were two kinds of data in one column and there are total 9000+ rows and several columns in the excel file/table, while the column with two kinds of data was just one of the columns.

[originaldata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQb7J.png)

```
ID Fruit/FruitJuice                                                        
  <dbl> <chr>                                                                          
1     1 NA/applejuice:15(ml)                                                         
2     2 banana:10(kg)/orangejuice:20(ml);tomatojuice:25(ml)                            
3     3 watermelon:10(kg)/NA                                                          
4     4 banana:5(kg);grape:6(kg)/orangejuice:30(ml);applejuice:50(ml);mangojuice:25(ml)
```

Briefly describe the data, the column with 2 kinds of data consist of fruit and fruit juice, that separated by "/", each of them have unit in bracket, while the objects in fruit or fruit juice were separated by ";".

Since the actual data frame was containing more column than the image I've shown, and I have done some searching online but I am still have no any idea how to solve it and wish to get the final table as below, can anyone lend me a hand? Thanks

[Final data wish-to-be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjzfX.png)

```
      ID `Fruit/FruitJuice`           
 1     1 Fruit_NA                     
 2     1 Fruitjuice_applejuice:15(ml) 
 3     2 Fruit_banana:10(kg)      
 4     2 Fruitjuice_orangejuice:20(ml)
 5     2 Fruitjuice_tomatojuice:25(ml)
 6     3 Fruit_watermelon:10(kg)      
 7     3 Fruitjuice_NA                
 8     4 Fruit_banana:5(kg)           
 9     4 Fruit_grape:6(kg)            
10     4 Fruitjuice_orangejuice:30(ml)
11     4 Fruitjuice_applejuice:50(ml) 
12     4 Fruitjuice_mangojuice:25(ml)
```

Comment: How should the output looks like?

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Don’t add data/code as images. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @nyk  I have updated, thanks for your help, and sorry for the inconvenience >.<

Comment: @RonakShah sorry that I am not familiar with this website yet, thanks for your suggestion, I will try to present my question in a more proper way next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
   separate(2,into = c("Fruit","FruitJuice"), sep = "/") %>%
   pivot_longer(-ID) %>% separate_rows(value, sep = ";") %>%
   summarise(ID = ID, `Fruit/FruitJuice` = str_c(name,"_",value))
# A tibble: 12 x 2
      ID `Fruit/FruitJuice`           
   <int> <chr>                        
 1     1 Fruit_NA                     
 2     1 FruitJuice_applejuice:15(ml) 
 3     2 Fruit_banana:10(kg)          
 4     2 FruitJuice_orangejuice:20(ml)
 5     2 FruitJuice_tomatojuice:25(ml)
 6     3 Fruit_watermelon:10(kg)      
 7     3 FruitJuice_NA                
 8     4 Fruit_banana:5(kg)           
 9     4 Fruit_grape:6(kg)            
10     4 FruitJuice_orangejuice:30(ml)
11     4 FruitJuice_applejuice:50(ml) 
12     4 FruitJuice_mangojuice:25(ml)
```

Comment: Hi @Ian Campbell, the solution given was perfectly solving the question. I have a question on separate() function that I am not clear with. What does the "2" stands for in the function, is it the number of column? 
Since the function was: separate( data, col, into, sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+", remove = TRUE, convert = FALSE, extra = "warn", fill = "warn", ... )

Comment: But that was just a part of column in my data, it actually consists of 24 columns, after I modified the coding, the console showed this :- 
Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has size 8031 but must be size 1.
Is there any else input coding should I modify?

Comment: I was worried this would be confusing. When you are defining `col =`, you can do it in many ways in the Tidyverse. Here, I chose the integer index of the column, `2`, for the second column. You could also use it's name `\`Fruit/FruitJuice\``. Or you can use one of the [tidyselect functions](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html).

Comment: Also note that the first argument `data = ` is automatically filled from the output of the left hand side of the `%>%` operator.

Comment: I tried to replace the `col =` with my column name, it shows `a tribble: number x 2`, even I have a total column of 24, I am not sure what happened. Is the `summarise function` should be modify too? I tried to create another dataset with just 2 columns it's actually work well, it's also shows `a tribble of number x 2` .

Comment: Also, can I make the output back into the dataset. It seems like it's not able to see the result of the solved output in the Data at the Global Environment there?